# retriving data from Firestore snapshot callback for Collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

in my node.js I have simple :

```
firestore.collection('companies').onSnapshot(comp=>{

})
```

that listens to new documents added/removed to collection , unfortunately I have problem to retrive data from "comp" when I try "comp.data()" like shown in the documentation I'm getting error:  "data is not a function":S 
what is the correct way to extract data here?

Comment: It seems you're omitting the actual code that's causing an error here.  Could you show that, as well as the reference to the documentation you're following?

Comment: figured it out just now have to ofc do "comp.forEach(c=>c.data())" @DougStevenson thank you nevertheless:)

Answer (score 0):

should be `comp.forEach(c => c.data())` for anyone that stacked with that silly mistake.